# Beautiful soup parsing XML incorrectly

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE pdf2xml SYSTEM "pdf2xml.dtd">
<page number="1" position="absolute" top="0" left="0" height="1188" width="918">
<text top="301" left="136" width="223" height="17" font="4"><b>– Jul-18            ABC  </b></text>
<text top="495" left="136" width="258" height="17" font="4"><b>– Aug-16</b>                     <b>XYZ                  </b></text>
</page>
```

Beautiful Soup using xml/lxml/lxml-xml parser doesn't parse the **second** `<text>` element correctly. It **removes the space** between `Aug-16` and `XYZ`. It parses it as

```
<text font="4" height="17" left="136" top="495" width="258"><b>– Aug-16</b> <b>XYZ                  </b></text>
```

which isn't correct. I have tried making the soup using `from_encoding="utf-8"` option too. None have worked.

Comment: can you add some more code snippet, how you get text? like using .text or get_text() method

Comment: I use get_text() on the text elements after selecting them using `soup.find_all('text')`

Answer (score 0):

May you need to try this way,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text = """
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE pdf2xml SYSTEM "pdf2xml.dtd">
<page number="1" position="absolute" top="0" left="0" height="1188" width="918">
<text top="301" left="136" width="223" height="17" font="4"><b>– Jul-18            ABC  </b></text>
<text top="495" left="136" width="258" height="17" font="4"><b>– Aug-16</b>                     <b>XYZ                  </b></text>
</page>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
for i in soup.find_all('text'):
    print(i.get_text(separator=u' ', strip=False))

#Output as : – Jul-18            ABC  
#             – Aug-16   XYZ
```

Comment: In your example as well, large number of spaces between `Aug-16` and `XYZ` are getting removed.

Comment: @AshutoshPathak actually in you xml text when parsed it shows like this,`<text font="4" height="17" left="136" top="301" width="223"><b>– Jul-18            ABC  </b></text>`
`<text font="4" height="17" left="136" top="495" width="258"><b>– Aug-16</b> <b>XYZ                  </b></text>` Not as you are thinking

Comment: See this is the issue. In actual xml, there are spaces between those but when BS4 parses it , those are removed. You can see by printing the soup elements themselves.

Comment: when you prettify this xml then it is converted like this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE pdf2xml SYSTEM "pdf2xml.dtd">
<page number="1" position="absolute" top="0" left="0" height="1188" width="918">
  <text top="301" left="136" width="223" height="17" font="4">
    <b>– Jul-18            ABC  </b>
  </text>
  <text top="495" left="136" width="258" height="17" font="4">
    <b>– Aug-16</b>
    <b>XYZ                  </b>
  </text>
</page>`
and bs4 and xml libraries working on tag basis not on space so it will not preserve the spaces in your case between two tags.